# properly join two files based on 2 columns in common

Tags: unix, join, awk

I have two files I'm trying to join/merge based on columns `1` and `2`. They look something like this, with `file1` (`58210` lines) being much shorter than `file2` (`815530` lines) and I'd like to find the intersection of these two files based on fields `1` and `2` as an index:

`file1`:

```
2L      25753   33158
2L      28813   33158
2L      31003   33158
2L      31077   33161
2L      31279   33161
3L      32124   45339
3L      33256   45339
...
```

`file2`:

```
2L      20242   0.5     0.307692307692308
2L      22141   0.32258064516129        0.692307692307692
2L      24439   0.413793103448276       0.625
2L      24710   0.371428571428571       0.631578947368421
2L      25753   0.967741935483871       0.869565217391304
2L      28813   0.181818181818182       0.692307692307692
2L      31003   0.36    0.666666666666667
2L      31077   0.611111111111111       0.931034482758621
2L      31279   0.75    1
3L      32124   0.558823529411765       0.857142857142857
3L      33256   0.769230769230769       0.90625
...
```

I've been using the following couple of commands but end up with different numbers of lines:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} {if($1$2 in a) print}' file1 file2 | wc -l
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} {if($1$2 in a) print}' file2 file1 | wc -l
```

I'm not sure why this happens, and I've tried sorting prior to comparison, just in case I have duplicate lines (based on columns `1` and `2`) in either of the files, but it doesn't seem to help. (Any insights on why this is so are also appreciated)

How can I just merge the files so that just the lines of `file2` that have the corresponding columns `1` and `2` in `file1` get printed, with column `3` of `file1` added on, to look something like this:

```
2L      25753   0.967741935483871       0.869565217391304    33158
2L      28813   0.181818181818182       0.692307692307692    33158
2L      31003   0.36    0.666666666666667    33158
2L      31077   0.611111111111111       0.931034482758621    33161
2L      31279   0.75    1    33161
3L      32124   0.558823529411765       0.857142857142857    45339
3L      33256   0.769230769230769       0.90625    45339
```

Comment: Can you give some examples where the first column varies?

Comment: what field(s) should be used to join rows?

Comment: Or they should be joined line by line?

Comment: Your sample data has no rows that should be matching...

Comment: You must have one file that was created on DOS and one on UNIX or something as there's got to be some kind of control characters at the end of the lines in one or both files that are messing with the output. Try "cat -v" on both file to see the control chars, and try dos2unix on both to fix them.

Comment: @Serge : apologies for the belated response, files needed to be joined based on fields 1 and 2 (hence in the question columns 1 and 2)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : you are right! Thank you for going to the trouble of revising the examples so that they work properly, I should have thought to do that myself in the original post.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file1 file2
```

Look:

```
$ cat file1
2L      5753   33158
2L      8813   33158
2L      7885   33159
2L      1279   33159
2L      5095   33158
$
$ cat file2
2L      8813    0.6    1.2
2L      5762    0.4    0.5
2L      1279    0.5    0.9
$
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file1 file2
2L      8813    0.6    1.2 33158
2L      1279    0.5    0.9 33159
$
```

If that's not what you want, please clarify and perhaps post some more representative sample input/output.

Commented version of the above code to provide requested explanation:

```
awk ' # START SCRIPT

# IF the number of records read so far across all files is equal
#    to the number of records read so far in the current file, a
#    condition which can only be true for the first file read, THEN 
NR==FNR {

   # populate array "a" such that the value indexed by the first
   # 2 fields from this record in file1 is the value of the third
   # field from the first file.
   a[$1,$2]=$3

   # Move on to the next record so we don't do any processing intended
   # for records from the second file. This is like an "else" for the
   # NR==FNR condition.
   next

} # END THEN

# We only reach this part of the code if the above condition is false,
# i.e. if the current record is from file2, not from file1.

# IF the array index constructed from the first 2 fields of the current
#    record exist in array a, as would occur if these same values existed
#    in file1, THEN
($1,$2) in a {

   # print the current record from file2 followed by the value from file1
   # that occurred at field 3 of the record that had the same values for
   # field 1 and field 2 in file1 as the current record from file2.
   print $0, a[$1,$2]

} # END THEN

' file1 file2 # END SCRIPT
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Then you have no matching rows in your input. The solution DOES work for the problem you described. Alternatively maybe you're using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). What does awk --version tell you?

Comment: You're right, your solution works. I checked on your file that you gave as an example. I've tried to file the post above. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No problem. Can't imagine why the OP saw fit to post large sample input files that would not produce any output and then an output line that didn't occur in that input. Just trying to make it more challenging for those of us trying to help I suppose.

Comment: I am a beginner in awk. Can you briefly explain what in turn makes your command?

Comment: @tedee12345: see modified answer above.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks so much, and sorry, you're right that the example was not that great, I just posted the heads of both the files as an example of what they look like but running code on those lines would not have produced an output, will definitely watch that in the future. Apologies to everyone else too!

Comment: @EdMorton I learned many tricks from you. and this answer with complete explanation deserve `nice answer` badge! +1!

Comment: Nice answer! Congrats for being 20K, entirely deserved for your awk guru-ism :)

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, now if I can just find a job where that's actually valuable :-).

Answer (score 6):

If you like to join the files line by line then use this command:

```
join -o 1.2,1.3,2.4,2.5,1.4 <(cat -n file1) <(cat -n file2)
```

As you updated the question:

```
join -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,1.2 <(sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/@/' file1|sort) \
    <(sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/@/' file2|sort)|sed 's/@/\t/'
```

First replace the first delimiter in each row with some non-space character and sort both input files. Then use `join` to make the actual join. Filter out its output to replace the non-space char with space.

This is the output from the files as in question:

```
xyz]$ join -o 1.1,2.2,2.3,1.2 <(sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/@/' file1|sort) \
<(sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/@/' file2|sort)|sed 's/@/\t/'

2L  25753 0.967741935483871 0.869565217391304 33158
2L  28813 0.181818181818182 0.692307692307692 33158
2L  31003 0.36 0.666666666666667 33158
2L  31077 0.611111111111111 0.931034482758621 33161
2L  31279 0.75 1 33161
3L  32124 0.558823529411765 0.857142857142857 45339
3L  33256 0.769230769230769 0.90625 45339
```

Comment: The join needs to be on columns 1 and 2, doesn't it?  And `join` only seems to work with a single column.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did not get any response from the OP on my questions, so I just assumed that the join to be done line by line, so I do the join on the line numbering produced by cat

Comment: OK — fair enough; I don't think that's what the OP had in mind, but I'd missed the `-n` on the `cat` commands (but then I subscribe to the New Jersey school for the design of `cat` and '`cat` came back from Berkeley waving flags`' (a paraphrase of a quote by Ken Thompson) annoys me).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I even can't understand why he is not surprised to get a single row of output provided that data and the requirement to join on columns 1 & 2.

Comment: @Serge I don't know sed well enough to figure out what's going on, but your updated answer does not produce the desired output, it actually increases the number of lines from either input files. I don't know if this helps, but field 1 is a character while field 2 is numerical. Both files are already sorted by field 1, then numerically sorted by field 2.

Comment: oh, where did you find out about these two <() <()? It's amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `join` command but you need to create a single join field in each data table.  Assuming that you do have values other that `2L` in column 1, then this code should work regardless of the sorted or unsorted nature of the two input files:

```
tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/tmp.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp.?; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

awk '{print $1 ":" $2, $0}' file1 | sort > $tmp.1
awk '{print $1 ":" $2, $0}' file2 | sort > $tmp.2

join -o 2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,1.4 $tmp.1 $tmp.2

rm -f $tmp.?
trap 0
```

If you have `bash` and 'process substitution', or if you know that the data is already sorted appropriately, you can simplify the processing.

---

I'm not entirely sure why your code wasn't working, but I'd probably be using `a[$1,$2]` for the subscripts; it will give you less trouble if some of your column 1 values are pure numeric and can therefore be confused when you concatenate columns 1 and 2.  That's why the 'key creation' `awk` scripts used a colon between the fields.

---

With revised data files as shown:

#### file1

```
2L      5753   33158
2L      8813   33158
2L      7885   33158
2L      7885   33159
2L      1279   33158
2L      5095   33158
2L      3256   33158
2L      5372   33158
2L      7088   33161
2L      5762   33161
```

#### file2

```
2L      5095    0.666666666666667       1
2L      5372    0.5     0.925925925925926
2L      5762    0.434782608695652       0.580645161290323
2L      5904    0.571428571428571       0.869565217391304
2L      5974    0.434782608695652       0.694444444444444
2L      6353    0.785714285714286       0.84
2L      7088    0.590909090909091       0.733333333333333
2L      7885    0.714285714285714       0.864864864864865
2L      7902    0.642857142857143       0.810810810810811
2L      8263    0.833333333333333       0.787878787878788
```

(Unchanged from the question.)

#### Output

```
2L 5095 0.666666666666667 1 33158
2L 5372 0.5 0.925925925925926 33158
2L 5762 0.434782608695652 0.580645161290323 33161
2L 7088 0.590909090909091 0.733333333333333 33161
2L 7885 0.714285714285714 0.864864864864865 33158
2L 7885 0.714285714285714 0.864864864864865 33159
```