# Linux commands to find two comparable rows

Tags: linux, sed

I have data in the following sorted order (Here the data is sorted according to first v1, then v2, then v3 and then v4):

```
v1=1    v2=8513481      v3=119330184    v4=0
 v1=1    v2=8521383      v3=119330182    v4=0
 v1=1    v2=10630231     v3=60529116     v4=18
 v1=1    v2=60528877     v3=60529221     v4=17
 v1=1    v2=90351079     v3=90351078     v4=20
 v1=1    v2=271669588    v3=271669683    v4=101
 v1=2    v2=8513481      v3=10583646     v4=0
 v1=2    v2=10175437     v3=10175436     v4=0
 v1=2    v2=10630231     v3=60528947     v4=17
 v1=2    v2=10630231     v3=60529119     v4=18
 v1=2    v2=10630232     v3=605291191     v4=18
```

Now I want to find out the rows where v1's and v2's of 2 lines are equal. i.e. amongst the data given above I want to find rows of the following form:

```
 v1=2    v2=10630231     v3=60528947     v4=17
 v1=2    v2=10630231     v3=60529119     v4=18
```

I know how to do so in python by comparing the successive rows and whenever there is a match outputing the row. Is there an easy way to do the same using linux commands like sed, etc. I know how to use sed to find words when two values are given, but I dont know how to use sed in this context. A bit of explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [properly join two files based on 2 columns in common](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994298/properly-join-two-files-based-on-2-columns-in-common)

Comment: @tripleee sorry but that guys question is on joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a little easier with `awk`:

```
awk '{
    lines[$1,$2]=(lines[$1,$2]?lines[$1,$2] RS $0:$0)
    dups[$1,$2]++
}
END {
    for(line in lines) 
        if(dups[line]>1) print lines[line]
}' file
v1=2    v2=10630231     v3=60528947     v4=17
v1=2    v2=10630231     v3=60529119     v4=18
```

- We create two arrays. `lines` and `dups`.
- We increment the count when first and second column are seen more than once. We use `dups` array for this.
- In our `lines` array, we check if we have stored a line with same first and second column. If we have we append the duplicate line to it.
- In the `END` block we iterate over `lines` array. If the first and column are found more than once in our `dups` array, we print the lines.

Alternatively, if you don't want to keep entire file in memory, you can do the following (since you stated your data is already sorted):

```
awk '($1==c1 && $2==c2){print line RS $0}{line=$0;c1=$1;c2=$2}' file
```

- We assign variables `line` as your entire current line, `c1` as column 1 and `c2` as column 2.
- If column 1 and 2 of current line and same as previous column1 and column2, print previous line and current line.

Comment: hey that's really cool..can u please point me to links from which i can learn such things about awk more

Comment: @JannatArora Sure, a good place to start would be [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) is a definitive guide.

Comment: +1 for the parsing once solution & explanation.  however keep in mind that `(x in y)` doesn't keep the insertion order.

Comment: @JannatArora Kent is right. Even though the previous solution will print the dups together, the order of those dups might not be same as they appear in the file. If order is important, I added another solution which assumes the file is sorted like you stated in question.

Answer (score 1):

First let me start by saying that the list your are showing is not strictly sorted in the Linux sense (spaces and tabs do affect the sorting). The best Linux solution for your question is to use awk. Here is a command that should do what you are looking for:

```
awk -e '{cur=$1 " " $2; if (NR>1 && cur==prev) {print "line:"NR " " cur} prev=cur}' < input_file
```

All this does is compare the string formed by the combination of the first and second columns of the input file ($1 and $2; separated by a space for cleaner output) which we call *cur* with the same string from the previous input line which we call *prev*. If the two strings match we output the line number and the result. We also add a condition to skip the first line of the file since there would be nothing to compare yet.

Comment: +1. Can u please explain this a little..i m new to awk

Comment: Notice that this is an on-line algorithm which means it never needs to grow memory or keep track of saved data no matter how large the input file is.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '$!N;/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+.*\n\s*\1\s+\2/p;D' file
```

This uses back references to compare two lines and prints those lines that duplicate the first two values.

However if the duplicates may be three or more successive lines another approach can be used. Duplicates are printed and flagged using the hold buffer. When a duplicate followed by a non-duplicate line is encounter the last duplicate line is also printed and the flag reset:

```
sed -rn '$!N;/^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+.*\n\s*\1\s+\2/{h;P;D};x;/./{z;x;P;D};x;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to find out how many characters are the same at the beginning of the line (looks like about 25?) and only compare that many via `uniq`:

```
uniq --check-chars=25 --repeated < input_file
```

To print both lines, use `--all-repeated` instead of `--repeated`.

Comment: Please explain what is not working. With the test data you provided, it worked perfectly.