# Merge tab-delimited files based on first 8 columns

Tags: unix, text, awk, merge

I have a tab-delimited file (let's call it file1) that looks like this:

```
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    5501    5691    .   -   .   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    16966   17019   .   -   .   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    23978   24241   .   -   .   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    43486   43714   .   -   .   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    61647   62139   .   -   .   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 5501    5691    .   -   2   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 16966   17019   .   -   2   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 23978   24241   .   -   2   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 43486   43633   .   -   0   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    160437  160638  .   -   .   gene_id "2"; transcript_id "2.1";
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    160913  161019  .   -   .   gene_id "2"; transcript_id "2.1";
```

And a larger tab-delim file (file2) that looks like this:

```
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  gene    5501    62139   .   -   .   ID=gene0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212;Name=LOC106560212;gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC106560212;gene_biotype=protein_coding
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  mRNA    5501    62139   .   -   .   ID=rna0;Parent=gene0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;Name=XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 99%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 8 samples with support for all annotated introns;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    61647   62139   .   -   .   ID=id1;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    43486   43714   .   -   .   ID=id2;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    23978   24241   .   -   .   ID=id3;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    16966   17019   .   -   .   ID=id4;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    5501    5691    .   -   .   ID=id5;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 43486   43633   .   -   0   ID=cds0;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XP_014016259.1;Name=XP_014016259.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;protein_id=XP_014016259.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 23978   24241   .   -   2   ID=cds0;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XP_014016259.1;Name=XP_014016259.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;protein_id=XP_014016259.1
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  CDS 16966   17019   .   -   2   ID=cds0;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XP_014016259.1;Name=XP_014016259.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;protein_id=XP_014016259.1
```

I would like to create a new file that only contains lines from file1 that are also present in file2, based on the first 8 columns, that has all 9 columns from file1 and column 9 of file2 as column 10. Like this:

```
NC_027300.1 Gnomon  exon    5501    5691    .   -   .   gene_id "1"; transcript_id "1.1"; ID=id5;Parent=rna0;Dbxref=GeneID:106560212,Genbank:XM_014160784.1;gbkey=mRNA;gene=LOC106560212;product=fibroblast growth factor receptor 3-like;transcript_id=XM_014160784.1
```

I have been trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994298/properly-join-two-files-based-on-2-columns-in-common) and this is (with my very limited knowledge) what I came up with:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]=$10;next} ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8) in a{print $0, a[$$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]}' file1 file2 > newfile
```

Could someone please tell me if I'm anywhere near and help if it's wrong? My files are 1M+ lines and this is running at the moment but I fear it could be a while before I can even see if it's working!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the input files order and tidy up:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ k = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7 FS $8 }
NR==FNR { a[k]=$9; next }
k in a { print $0, a[k] }
' file2 file1
```

Comment: This works perfectly for smaller files but when trying to use on large files (>700MB, >1M lines) I get this after a while: Segmentation fault (core dumped).
Is there an alternative to awk that may handle it better? A Perl script alternative perhaps?

Comment: Obviously that;s happening because youre trying to read a massive file into memory. If you implemented this approach in perl or ruby or any other tool youd have the same problem and if you adopt a different approach it'll work in awk just like it would in perl, ruby, etc. Nothing magic about any specific tool for processing text. Since it's been 4 months since you posted this question, no-one is going to revisit it now to try to come up with a different approach so I suggest you accept this answer since it fixed your script and then post a new question with the relevant info about the segv.

Answer (score 1):

You are on right path, look like you need small correction

Change

```
a[$$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]
  ^
 Here
```

To

```
a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8]
```

So that it will print 10th field from file1 which is in array `a`, if index key made of 8 fields from file2 exists in array `a` which was created using 1st 8 fields of file1.