# Join Two Files Based on TWO Columns in Common

Tags: linux, bash, awk, merge

I have two files I'm trying to join/merge based on first and second columns. Below is the desired output, what I am looking for. I want to highlight one thing, I would like to merge these two files, not the intersection only. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$ cat file1
2L      5753   33158
2L      8813   33158
2L      7885   33159
2L      1279   33159
2L      5095   33158
$
$ cat file2
2L      8813    0.6    1.2
2L      5762    0.4    0.5
2L      1279    0.5    0.9
$

Desired Output:
2L      5753                33158
2L      8813    0.6    1.2  33158
2L      7885                33159
2L      1279    0.5    0.9  33159
2L      5095                33158
2L      5762    0.4    0.5
```

I found a similar post but it seems like it needs some tweak to meet what I am thinking about. URL is : 
[Similar Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994298/properly-join-two-files-based-on-2-columns-in-common)

Comment: What is the separator in your files? Multiple spaces or one tabulator?

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks! There are multiple spaces between the columns!

Comment: And what tweak have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following bash script reads each line from file1, extracts the corresponding line from (a copy of) file2, merges both lines, and prints the result to stdout. Finally, file2 (what's left of it) is printed.

```sh
temp=$(mktemp)
cp file2 $temp
while read col1 col2 arg3; do
  line=$(sed -r -i -e "/^$col1\ +$col2/ {w /dev/stdout" -e "d}" $temp)
  arg1=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< $line)
  arg1=${arg1:-   }
  arg2=$(awk '{print $4}' <<< $line)
  arg2=${arg2:-   }
  echo -e "$col1\t$col2\t$arg1    $arg2\t$arg3"
done < file1
cat $temp
rm $temp
```

The idea for the `sed` command was taken from dhakimian's extension of Gilles' answer on [Printing and deleting the first line of a file using `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108335/printing-and-deleting-the-first-line-of-a-file-using-sed).

Answer (score 0):

With `gawk`:

```
$ gawk -F$'\t' -v OFS=$'\t' 'FNR==NR{l[$1,$2]=$0; next}  
                       l[$1,$2]{print l[$1,$2],$3; delete l[$1,$2]; next} 
                        {print $1,$2,OFS,$3}
                        END{for (e in l) if(l[e]) print l[e]}' f2 f1
2L  5753            33158
2L  8813    0.6 1.2 33158
2L  7885            33159
2L  1279    0.5 0.9 33159
2L  5095            33158
2L  5762    0.4 0.5
```

This assumes `\t` separating the fields.